# Is GPU mining viable with any Cryptocurrency mining variations?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware

I have a GTX 960 2GB, and wouldn't mind some cash. I know mining bitcoin with it would maybe produce a few pennies a year, but someone told me there are other mining networks that aren't as inflated as Bitcoin. Also, I'm thinking about upgrading to a 1060 soon (for gaming) and use that for mining overnight/during school, if viable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to keep your eye on a cryptocurrency mining profitability website such as this:

http://www.coinwarz.com/cryptocurrency

Please note that much of the mining software for a lot of these coins contain malware, so be very, very careful before installing such things.

Comment: What mining software should I use then? Is cgminer?

Comment: depends on the altcoin. They usually have some modification on cgminer or bfgminer that you need to download which allows you to mine that particular coin.